# Delete doesn't show on profile, but shows on feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am following MHartl's book for Rails 3.2

In chapter 10, he adds delete links for the microposts on the homepage and profile page

My problem is that delete links show for homepage but not profile page.

```
     <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
            <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete,
                     confirm: "You sure?",
                     title: micropost.content %>
      <% end %>
```

This is for the feed:

```
       <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
             <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                     confirm: "You sure?",
                     title: feed_item.content %>
       <% end %>
```

It is the same user so I do not know why delete links won't show.

I mean, the only reason why this would not show is if I am not signed in, but it is showing for feed_item.user

Also, I am signed in so it should show. If I create a new micropost, it will get posted to the right user.

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: You could probably debug a bit with showing the user.id just to be 100% sure.

Comment: How do I do that. Thanks for responding!

Comment: You have the current_user helper method so just display the user ID like `<%=current_user.id%>` (or whatever the id column is called) and then for each feed_item do `<%=feed_item.user.id%>`. Generally I can`t seem to understand why `current_user?(feed_item.user)` won`t work. The only possible reason is that the current user actually IS NOT the owner of the feed_item.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurred to me and I fixed it by adding `<% current_user %>` before it